# Tubelights+power lines pictures?

Tags: energy, electricity, potential, electric-fields

I've come across many pictures like [these](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=power%20lines%20tubelights&qscrl=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=sOFIT92uFKbnmAXc-_z0DQ&biw=1124&bih=557&sei=u-FIT9_dBu7FmQXemL3_DQ#um=1&hl=en&qscrl=1&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=u-FIT_C_GZCfmQW_ycGfDg&ved=0CD0QBSgA&q=power%20lines%20tube%20lights&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=de4497a4e86ac59a&biw=1124&bih=557), sometimes in chain emails reporting the dangers of power lines.

Another claim is that they [run on "wasted" energy](http://www.stopgeek.com/richard-boxs-light-field.html).

The explanations given are that the wires set up a field, and thus a potential difference. This p.d. gives current in the wires.

Now, I can't help but feeling skeptical. I can't see how the tubes would stay lit for the time it takes to set up the whole grid. Here's my logic:

If current flows through the tubelight, there will be a net charge distribution on the caps. At one point, the charge distribution will be such that it creates its own potential, halting the flow of light. This works even if one end is grounded. An easier way to analyse this is a capacitor (GP: G for ground, P for power lines), with a bulb inside it. Each terminal of the bulb is connected to a plate (A and B).  There's an optional grounding wire W. In this situation, it's obvious that eventually the plates AB will get enough charge (same charge density as PG incidentally) to create zero p.d. Current should be there for a brief moment in time.

[image: diagram]

I understand that this is a DC situation, but for power lines, I think that something similar should happen. Or maybe not. I'm clear that the potential difference across the live and neutral switches polarities, but I'm not sure how the potential field is outside the wire. In fact, I feel that there shouldn't be a V/E field, only a magnetic field.

If it's true that the tubelights stay lit, then how is the energy "wasted energy"? I feel that even if the tubelight can stay lit, the energy is being drawn from the power lines. This looks just like how one can naively say that there is energy wasted in an open socket; when in reality plugging something in draws more energy from the system (and can dim other appliances).

**Update**: So my questions are thus:

1. I'd like a clearer explanation of the potential and E field outside an AC power line.
2. Is the energy "wasted energy"?

Comment: Note that power-lines are AC. How does that change your analysis?

Comment: @dmckee I have written that (right below the diagram). I'm not exactly clear about the field and potential outside an AC wire. I'd like aclearer explanation than my muddled thoughts.

Comment: Imagine adding a switch between the battery and the rest of your circuit and turning it on and off really fast. The current is there for a brief moment every time you turn it on, and flows in the opposite direction when you turn it off. AC is basically like this, and if this thing with the tube lights works, then I imagine that's how.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda understood that, but I'd like a more detailed explanation, especially of the "power loss"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric field of a transmission line decreases with the distance from the line, so there is a potential difference in the radial direction. This potential difference can cause the glow in fluorescent tubes. I believe such tubes can glow even if it is a DC transmission line, as the charge can drift in the air. You may wish to consider a comparison with a corona discharge, which often takes place near transmission lines (both DC and AC), even if there are no fluorescent tubes around, because the electric field strength can be so high near the conductor that causes air breakdown. Corona discharge causes extra power losses, so do glowing fluorescent tubes. While there are losses even in open AC circuits due to reactive loads, extra load leads to extra losses. So those fluorescent bulbs do cause extra losses, they don't use just "wasted energy". Furthermore, I am not sure it is safe to fool around transmission lines.

Comment: Could you explain how the E field is formed? That's part of my confusion; I see no cause for a field. No charges &c, the wire is neutral. Unless the time varying B field creates an E field or something. But that wouldn't happen in the case of DC current.

Comment: I don't quite see how the wire can be neutral everywhere. The wire has finite resistivity, so the wire potential varies (approximately linearly) along the wire, otherwise there is no direct current. Therefore, the wire cannot be neutral everywhere, so typically there is a potential difference between the wire and the ground, therefore, there is electric field.

Comment: I understood that as well. From a basics point of view, where does the E come from? E should still obey Gauss' law. It looks as if it's emenating from the wire and latching onto the sheet, which implies that the wire has net charge density.. Where exactly is the cjarge source of it. Field causes potential, not the other way around. The only source of E I cam see is a time varying B. But that doesnt explain where theE comes from in the DC case.

Comment: @Manishearth: My understanding is as follows. If there is direct current, that means there is a closed circuit. As there is no superconductivity (I don't consider any exotic systems here), that means there is a DC generator in the circuit, which basically separates negative and positive charges. These charges get distributed over the surface of the wire and create electric field.

Comment: @akhmateli Really? But then the same mechanism won't work for AC. And the magnetic-field-thing is just something I wanted to throw out there, it won't really be large enough to give a large enough field. Ideally, AC and DC should have the same source of field, but charge distribution doesn't seem to work for AC.

Comment: I'll post another question on this asking for more details.

Comment: @Manishearth: Why do you think this mechanism won't work for AC?

Comment: The charges will have to rapidly oscillate. Movement of charges takes time.

Comment: Aside from that, the charge would have to be dependant on ABSOLUTE potential, which makes no sense. Absolute potential is an arbitrary thing.

Comment: Lets take a simpler case. I have two long parallel wires.They are joined at one end by a battery, an d a resistor on the other end. Now, there will be a field whose line integral gives V. Now, if we increase the distance between the wires, in your model, the charge distribution won't change, as its a result of t he battery and nothing else. But it has to change to maintain the line integral.

Comment: @Manishearth: 1) The oscillation period is greater than 0.01 s. This is an eternity for electricity. There may be phase difference between oscillations of charge and potential, but why is this important for our discussion? 2) The charge on a certain section of a power line is determined by the potential difference between the ends of this section.3) I don't see why the charge distribution has to change significantly. The changing magnetic field does not affect the charges significantly.

Comment: We're increasing the distance over which the line integral is being carried out. But, it's final value is the same. Assuming equal and opposite charge distribution on both wires, the E fields will add up. So, there is no "sink" of E field, so to keep the line integral the same, E must decrease somewhere. For that, the charge magnitude has to decrease. I'm not considering magnetic fields.

Comment: @Manishearth: I believe your generator is a "sink".

Comment: That's why the  wires are long. The generator has no effect on the E, except by indirectly changing charge distribution.

Comment: @Manishearth: It is my understanding that, no matter how long the wires are, after some transient processes, the generator will determine the charges, the potentials, and the fields - we have forced oscillations here.

Comment: Any idea what the process is and how the charges are determined? Links are fine. Actually, this stuff would be better placed on [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21611/origin-of-field-deduced-from-potential). Off topic for this one.
I'm rather confused about this whole field-in-circuits thing.

Comment: @Manishearth: http://www.astrophysik.uni-kiel.de/~hhaertel/PUB/voltage_IRL.pdf (it's pretty much the same for AC)

Comment: Thanks. That question got answered as well due to the link :D. Posted a CW answer, feel free to add to it.